# Reach useRef() Current property return unidentified though using UseEffect to fire when adding a child element inside a Div

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-ref

I am new to react and understanding react Hooks, i am creating a small application where I am Dynamically creating Bar using adding Div elements. For this Purpose I am using useRef() and UseEffect() to render after every change on the div element, though I know the initial value is set to null that is why it is returning unidentified value , i really want to understand how can i initialize or any workaround. Below is my Code

```js
import React from "react";
import { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./ExpenseFilter.css";

const ExpenseFilter = (props) => {
  const values = [100, 100, 340, 320, 500, 50, 45, 385, 95, 120, 90, 20];
  const [refState, setrefState] = useState();
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ref.current);
  }, [refState]);

  const drawChart = (data, padding) => {
    const max = Math.max.apply(Math, data);
    const chart = ref.current;
    console.log(chart);
    const barwidth =
      (chart.offsetWidth - (values.length - 1) * padding - data.length * 10) /
      data.length;
    console.log(barwidth);
    let left = 0;
    for (let i in data) {
      let newbar = document.createElement("div");
      newbar.setAttribute("class", "bar");
      newbar.style.width = barwidth + "px";
      newbar.style.height = (data[i] / max) * 100 + "%";
      newbar.style.left = left + "px";
      chart.appendChild(newbar);
      left += barwidth + padding + 10;
      props.OnChangeDiv(newbar);
    }
  };
  drawChart(values, 15);

  return (
    <div className="wrapper1">
      <div className="select" tabIndex="1">
        <input
          className="selectopt"
          name="test"
          type="radio"
          id="opt1"
          checked
        />
        <label for="opt1" class="option">
          2019
        </label>
        <input className="selectopt" name="test" type="radio" id="opt2" />
        <label for="opt2" class="option">
          2020
        </label>
        <input className="selectopt" name="test" type="radio" id="opt3" />
        <label for="opt3" class="option">
          2021
        </label>
        <input className="selectopt" name="test" type="radio" id="opt4" />
        <label for="opt4" class="option">
          2022
        </label>
        <input className="selectopt" name="test" type="radio" id="opt5" />
        <label for="opt5" class="option">
          2023
        </label>
      </div>
      <div
        id="chart"
        ref={(el) => {
          setrefState(el);
        }}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ExpenseFilter;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: 1. You don't ever assign to ref.current 2. Using `document.createElement` with React is a very bad pattern.

Comment: @sun isn't the current property holds the object value?. 2. yeah you are right since I started learning React need to adapt. Any Suggestion on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for looking into this, I solved this one myself. So as I said earlier the initial value that is assigned to useRef() was null we all know which is why the current property was being set to unidentified. what I did is I have placed a condition on the ref that if it is unidentified then it should return and used useState hooks to fire capture the states and once it changes in the state it fires the useEffect() to re-render the current state.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (!ref.current) {
      return;
    }
    ref.current = refState;
    console.log(ref.current);
  }, [refState]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
<div
        id="chart"
        ref={(el) => {
          ref.current = el;
          setrefState(el);
        }}
      ></div>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

using the next State if the ref.

Answer (score 0):

Something isn't right there about how you're using the reference.

```
const ref = useRef()

...

<div ref={ref}>Example</div>

// ref.current is now <div>Example</div>
```

Comment: Yeah that’s what I want to send as a reference. And it does the job .. the problem is with initialisation.. since the initial value of the ref is being set to null the ref current property is being set to unidentified and useEffect is not able to rerender the next state of ref.

Comment: Perhaps this is what you're looking for https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node.